# Local changes on s3-cloudformation-template.json are overriden on amplify push

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

As part of my backend configuration, I need that an S3 bucket to get its objects automatically expired after 1 day. I included the S3 bucket to my backend with `amplify storage add`, but AMPLIFY-CLI is a bit limited on which can be configured for buckets.

So, after creating the bucket through amplify, I opened `s3-cloudformation-template.json` and manualy included a rule for object expiration:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "S3 resource stack creation using Amplify CLI",
    "Parameters": {...},
    "Conditions": {...},
    "Resources": {
        "S3Bucket": {
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            
            "DependsOn": [
                "TriggerPermissions"
            ],
            
            "DeletionPolicy" : "Retain",
            "Properties": {
                "BucketName": {...},
                
                "NotificationConfiguration": {...},
                
                "CorsConfiguration": {...},

                "LifecycleConfiguration": {
                    "Rules": [
                        {
                            "Id": "ExpirationRule",
                            "Status": "Enabled",
                            "ExpirationInDays": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
    ...
}
```

After that, I issued an `amplify status`, where the change in the cloudformation template was detected:

```
| Category | Resource name       | Operation | Provider plugin   |
| -------- | ------------------- | --------- | ----------------- |
| Storage  | teststorage         | Update    | awscloudformation |
```

Finally, I issued an `amplify push` but the command finished without any cloudformation logs for this change, and a new indication of `No Change` for the S3 storage:

```
✔ Successfully pulled backend environment dev from the cloud.

Current Environment: dev

| Category | Resource name       | Operation | Provider plugin   |
| -------- | ------------------- | --------- | ----------------- |
| Storage  | teststorage         | No Change | awscloudformation |
```

Checking `s3-cloudformation-template.json` again I noticed that the configuration I've added before was overriden/removed during the `push` command:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "S3 resource stack creation using Amplify CLI",
    "Parameters": {...},
    "Conditions": {...},
    "Resources": {
        "S3Bucket": {
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            
            "DependsOn": [
                "TriggerPermissions"
            ],
            
            "DeletionPolicy" : "Retain",
            "Properties": {
                "BucketName": {...},
                
                "NotificationConfiguration": {...},
                
                "CorsConfiguration": {...}
            }
        },
    ...
}
```

So, pretty sure I'm making some mistake here since I couldn't find other posts with this problem, but, where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You need to "override" the s3 bucket configuration ([Override Amplify-generated S3](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/storage/override/))...

From the command line type:

```
amplify override storage
```

This will show:

```
✅ Successfully generated "override.ts" folder at C:\myProject\amplify\backend\storage\staticData
√ Do you want to edit override.ts file now? (Y/n) · yes
```

Press Return to choose yes then update the override.ts file with the following:

```
import { AmplifyS3ResourceTemplate } from '@aws-amplify/cli-extensibility-helper'
import * as s3 from '@aws-cdk/aws-s3'

export function override(resources: AmplifyS3ResourceTemplate) {
  const lifecycleConfigurationProperty: s3.CfnBucket.LifecycleConfigurationProperty =
    {
      rules: [
        {
          status: 'Enabled',
          id: 'ExpirationRule',
          expirationInDays: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  resources.s3Bucket.lifecycleConfiguration = lifecycleConfigurationProperty
}
```

Back to the command line, press Return to continue:

```
Edit the file in your editor: C:\myProject\amplify\backend\storage\staticData\override.ts
? Press enter to continue
```

Now update the backend using:

```
amplify push
```

And you're done.

Further information on the configuration options can be found at [interface LifecycleConfigurationProperty](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3.CfnBucket.LifecycleConfigurationProperty.html)
Further information on what else can be overridden for the S3 bucket can be found at [class CfnBucket (construct)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3.CfnBucket.html)