# Update S3 bucket policy for a Amplify-generated S3 via CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify

Is it possible to update or insert a new S3 bucket policy to a Amplify-generated S3 using amplify override storage via CloudFormation? The documentation doesn't provide enough information on this. https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/storage/override/

Comment: I don't know much about Amplify, but generally you cannot *modify* a resource using CloudFormation directly, you can with a custom resource.  Have you investigated defining the Amplify deployment using CloudFormation?  If so, you *might* be able to create the bucket in CloudFormation with your bucket policy and *use* the bucket in Amplify?

Comment: What Tim Bassett said or conversely make the s3 bucket an Output in your CFN template that you can use (via another CFN template or the same) to apply the IAM permissions. Don't forget you can update CFN stacks and it records the "drift".

Answer (score 0):

You can't override the S3 bucket policy using

```
amplify override storage
```

A list of the properties you can override can be found at [class CfnBucket (construct)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3.CfnBucket.html)

I think the closest you could get is to supply a [canned acl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/acl-overview.html#canned-acl) as part of the overide...

From the command line type:

```
amplify override storage
```

This will show:

```
✅ Successfully generated "override.ts" folder at C:\myProject\amplify\backend\storage\staticData
√ Do you want to edit override.ts file now? (Y/n) · yes
```

Press Return to choose yes then update the override.ts file with the following:

```
import { AmplifyS3ResourceTemplate } from '@aws-amplify/cli-extensibility-helper'

export function override(resources: AmplifyS3ResourceTemplate) {
  resources.s3Bucket.accessControl = 'public-read'
}
```

You could then change `public-read` to any one of the [canned acl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/acl-overview.html#canned-acl)s

You then need to update the backend using:

```
amplify push
```

For anyone coming to this looking to override properties on an amplify created S3 bucket, a possibly more useful answer, overriding the lifecycle policy, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71584038/2591187)